# How to actually intercept res.render

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to intercept every call to render, do my own stuff, and then proceed with the original render method. I know this can easily be done through a middleware like this:

```js
function (req, res, next) {
  var _render = render;
  res.render = function () {
    // custom stuff
    _render.apply(this, arguments);
  }
  next();
}
```

However it seems more efficient to just change the prototype of the response object instead of replacing res.render on every request. I tried [such a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285880/node-js-express-js-how-to-override-intercept-res-render-function#answer-9294574) with no success. When logging `http.ServerResponse.prototype` there's no trace of any render method.

Finally i've tried to just intercept app.render instead, like this:

```js
var _render = app.render;
app.render = function () {
  // this is refering to app instead of res...
  _render.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

That does fulfill my criteria of only being done once, **but** it is called on the app object and not the res object which means I can't access the res or req objects.

Basically what I think I would like to do is something like:

```js
var _render = something.response.render;
something.response.render = function (view, data, callback) {
  // Access res.*, as this.*
  _render.call(this, view, data, callback);
};
```

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that it depends on Express version. Try this for 3.x:

```
var response = require( "express" ).response;

var _render = response.render;
response.render = function( ) {
    // do your stuff
    _render.apply( this, arguments );
};
```