# Override Node.js Express response method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to slightly change default expressjs behaviour of `res.json(obj)` method. I am trying to override it in my own middleware, the thing is I need to call its original inside.

But now it just calls itself causing a stack overflow.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.json = function(obj) {
        function delete_null_properties(obj) {
            // ...
        }
        delete_null_properties(obj);

        res.json(obj);
    };
    next();
});
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I think you are fixing the wrong problem... can you explain what you want to achieve, ie what you need to change?

Comment: @Sergio, It shown in the code. I want the same `json`, but without null keys. I want it to be transparent inside overall application, like default approach.

Comment: But `res.json` will send response back to client side... and you have a `next()` after. You are interfering with one of Expresses's response to clienth methods. I am sure you can fix you problem in another way.

Comment: would it be anything like overriding the res.render method - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285880/node-js-express-js-how-to-override-intercept-res-render-function

Comment: @Sergio, why do you think interfering expresses's methods is bad? Do you think it could break functionality in modules that could strictly rely on this method? Anyway, I don't think there's much of a change to worry about in case of deleting nulls.

Comment: @user3537411 why to use a framework? many smart people spent time making it as it is now so I don't see the point of changing it. I feel you are fixing the problem in the wrong moment of the logic.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't know the inner workings of express very well, but it seems something like this should work

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var json = res.json;
    res.json = function(obj) {
        function delete_null_properties(obj) {
            // ...
        }
        delete_null_properties(obj);

        json.call(this, obj);
    };
    next();
});
```

edit: changed `json(obj)` to `json.call(this, obj)` as per comment by [user3537411](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3537411/user3537411) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285880/node-js-express-js-how-to-override-intercept-res-render-function) previous answer to a similar question

P.S. I started the answer with *I don't know the inner workings of express very well* to avoid the sort of comments that just put crap on an answer without really going into WHY an answer is bad ... instead I get the sort of comment that's equally pointless. You can't win with SO trolls

Comment: Where are you calling `res.json()`?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, 3 wrong things in my opinion. First is that you are overriding a send method and never even calling it, you are passing a function to it and calling `next()`after it... Oh, and I'm not the one asking the question.

Comment: @Sergio - simple mistake, I meant *THE question* - not *your question*

Comment: @JaromandaX no problem. Main part of my comment was to answer your (now deleted) comment asking what was wrong with your answer.

Comment: @JaromandaX, thanks! Your answer would work with a little change: `var _json = res.json;` and `_json.call(this, obj);`

Comment: why _json? you can use `json` ... `_` has no significance

Comment: @JaromandaX, yeah, my mistake. Than just `json.call(this, obj);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below, after `const app = express();`  dont use this.json and dont use this.send inside the function otherwise you will get a maximum call size error :

```
app.response.json = function(body: any) {
    this.contentType('json').end(JSON.stringify(
      {
          code: ApiCode.OPERATION_SUCCES,
          message: CommonMessages.OperationSuccess.message,
          data: body,
          description: CommonMessages.OperationSuccess.description
        }
    ));
    return this; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It also might be useful

https://github.com/muratcorlu/connect-api-mocker/pull/30

Mounting twice will apply only last one.

```
const express = require('../../node_modules/express');

const app = express();

// default response
app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
  next();

  try {
    res.send({
      profile: {
        first_name: 'Aaron',
        last_name: 'Pol'
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {
    //
  }
});

// definite state, where default response can be changed
app.use('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send({
    profile: {
      first_name: 'John',
      last_name: 'Pol'
    }
  });
});

app.listen(9090);
```