# How to add data to automatically add data to every Express res.render call?

Tags: node.js, express

In my Express 4 server I have a middleware function that checks whether the user is signed in or not and adjusts the request accordingly.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const { IdToken } = req.signedCookies;
  if (!IdToken) {
    req.signedIn = false;
  } else {
    // TODO: Verify IdToken
    req.signedIn = true;
  }
  next();
});
```

Currently, in every route I manually add the signed-in state to every `res.render`.

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { signedIn: req.signedIn });
});
```

Can I somehow include this information without manually adding it to every `res.render` call?

Answer (score -1):

Add a middleware that adds a `req.view` function, and a `req.addState` function.

```
function addViewer(req, res, next) {
  req.state = {}
  req.addState = function(key, value) {
     req.state[key] = value
  }
  res.view = function(viewName, moreState) {
    res.render(viewName, Object.assign({}, req.state, moreState));
  }
  next();
}
```

Now you can call `res.view` instead of `res.render`. Note that you can make the view function a lot more powerful and the `addState` more customizable.

Comment: You want every incoming request to execute this function? Because that's what middlewares do. Maybe you can instead define a custom `view` function once and use it instead of `res.render`.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32874084/1362294 for a great solution to this.

Comment: it is actually a very bad solution, and focusing on an extra function call to evaluate if this is a good code or not is a very bad way to build web