# Override every res.render to res.json in the whole app

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I want to turn every `res.render` to `res.json` for the whole application. The reason I'm doing so is to avoid bad code as only in development environment, I would like to return JSON rather than HTML.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9285880/1951298) and following the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9294574/1951298) I thought it would work with:

```
const renderToJson = function(req, res, next) {
  res.render = function(view, options, callback) {
    res.status(200).json(res, view, options, callback);
  };
};
app.use(renderToJson);
```

Or

```
const renderToJson = function(req, res, next) {
  const _render = res.status(200).json;
  res.render = function(view, options, callback) {
    _render.call(res, view, options, callback);
  };
};
app.use(renderToJson);
```

But unfortunately it didn't. I continue to receive HTML with no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could obtain what I wanted with

```
const renderToJson = function(req, res, next) {
  let _render = res.render;
  res.render = function(view, options, callback) {
    this.json(options);
  };
  next();
};
app.use(renderToJson);
```

Keeping my response not approved as there might be drawbacks for this.